# What limit rocket final speed if there is no drag?

Tags: conservation-laws, speed-of-light, drag, speed, rocket-science

If thrust is constant and drag dont exist, speed goes to infinity or in relativistic physics to speed of light.

Even in relativistic theory mass of rocket increase with speed that will just reduce acceleration but not final speed..

So what limit rocket final speed if no drag in space?
Or rocket accelerating all the time when has fuel ?

So basically lack of fuel limit final speed?

Comment: Fuel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Answer (score 2):

The cosmic microwave background (CMB) will be a source of drag.

As you move to relativistic speeds the CMB will become highly anisotropic and there will be a net radiation pressure that exerts a force opposite to the momentum of the rocket. This force will increase with the rocket speed with respect to the stationary frame of the background, so ultimately must prevent any increase in that speed.

The top speed would depend on the thrust, the cross-sectional area of your rocket and its reflectivity.

If you (by magic) eliminate the cosmic microwave background then any object with mass can only approach the speed of light by attaining an arbitrarily large kinetic energy. But then, if you're using magic, anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Einstein's theory of Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) tells us that the speed of light is the maximum speed we can ever hope to achieve. It also tells us that constant thrust will not even lead get us as fast as light speed. As the speed of the rocket increases, it's relativistic (total) [mass increases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass) as per:$$m_{rel}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Here $m$ is the invariant mass or "rest mass", the mass the rocket has at zero speed. $v$ is the speed of the rocket, and $c$ is the speed of light.

The equation tells us that, as speed increases, the thrust required to keep the same acceleration also increases, and the rocket would need infinite thrust to reach $c$.

The [Breakthrough Starshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot) project plans to achieve up to 20% of $c$ at some time in the future, by launching solar sails propelled by gigantic lasers.

The fastest speed achieved by a spacecraft to date is 466,592 km/h or 129 km/s. That speed is achieved by the Parker Solar Probe, and is relative to the sun

Comment: Constant thrust (in a perfect vacuum) allows the rocket ship to asymptotically approach $c$. For constant acceleration $a$ (as experienced by the rocket's passengers), $\frac vc=\tanh\left(\frac{a\tau}c\right)$, where $\tau$ is proper time (i.e., ship time). Why would you want to increase the thrust? That wouldn't be very nice for the passengers. ;) See https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html

Comment: @hdhondt But  increase in rocket mass can just reduce acceleration but not final speed.Dont understand what limit final speed?

Comment: If the mass were infinite, no further increase in speed would be possible, regardless of thrust. As the speed approaches c, mass increases without limit and acceleration decreases, hence c will never be reached.